# Undefined reference to functions called from the static library

Tags: c, makefile

> I got this error when i launched make "undefined reference to this
> functions" : How can i solve the problem ?

tvi-stwunt@es7-stkw-dev-workstation:/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp> make
gcc -L/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp -lrabbitmq -lamqp  amqp_consommateur.o -o amqp_consommateur
amqp_consommateur.o: In function `main': /home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp/amqp_consommateur.c:48: undefined reference to` amqp_connexion'
/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp/amqp_consommateur.c:49: undefined reference to `amqp_consommateur' /home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp/amqp_consommateur.c:50: undefined reference to` amqp_deconnexion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [amqp_consommateur] Error 1

This is my c function which contain the main

```
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    #include <amqp.h>
    #include <amqp_tcp_socket.h>
    
    #include "libamqp.h"
    #include "amqp_outils.h"
    
    int main(int argc, char const *const *argv) {
        amqp_connection_state_t conn;
        char const *cle_liaison;
        char const *echange;
        char const *nom_hote;
        int port;
        char const *queue;
    
        nom_hote = argv[1];
        port = atoi(argv[2]);
        queue = argv[3];
        echange = "amq.direct";   /* argv[3]; */
        cle_liaison = "test queue"; /* argv[4]; */
    
        conn = amqp_new_connection();
        amqp_connexion(conn, nom_hote, port, echange, cle_liaison, queue);
        amqp_consommateur(conn, cle_liaison, echange);
        amqp_deconnexion(conn);
    
    
    return 0;
    }
```

> This is the Makefile

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -g
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/ -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp/dlo 
LFLAGS := -L/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp
LDLIBS := -lrabbitmq
SRCS := amqp_consommateur.c amqp_producteur.c
#LIBS := -L. -lamqp

OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
PROGS := $(SRCS:.c=)

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGS)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est généré"

$(PROGS) : % : %.o Makefile 
    $(CC) $(LDLIBS) $(LFLAGS) $< -o $@ 

clean:
    rm -f $(PROGS) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<
```

[image]

> My goal is to generate the executable for
> the two files amqp_consommateur and amqp_producteur

Comment: the resulting command must link in the libraru. none of the variables help since you have explicitly specified the linking command as not using any of them

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : i didn't understand your response.

Comment: `$(CC) $< -o $@` uses none of these variables

Comment: You define a variable `LIBS`, which contains libraries which you presumably need.  Libraries are used at **link time** but you have added them to the **compiler** command: compile steps don't use libraries.  You have to add them to the link line (the command that generates the final program).  If you look at the link command make prints you can see, that the libraries are not there.  So you know you have the wrong link command.

Comment: @MadScientist : how can i resolve this wrong link command ?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : $(CC) $(LDLIBS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@  , is that good ?

Comment: See my comment on the answer below.  The order of `LDLIBS` is important.

Comment: @MadScientist: unfortunately the same problem occured

Comment: In that case, the symbol `amqp_connexion` (etc.) is not present in the library `amqp`.  Are you sure that shouldn't be written using American English: `amqp_connection` ?

Comment: @MadScientist :yes i'm sure is written in French and  i added a picture, to demonstrate the folders of my library

Comment: The names of the files are irrelevant.  The only thing that matters is the names of the functions inside the file.  If the names of the functions are `amqp_connexion` in the source, and you're getting that link error even when you list the library last, then it must be that the library doesn't contain those symbols.  Maybe you built the library incorrectly.  If you run `ar t libamqp.a` does it show the `.o` files that contain the function implementation?

Comment: @MadScientist: yes when i run ar t libamqp.a,  it show the .o files that contain the function implementation

Comment: If you run `nm libamqp.a | grep amqp_connexion` what does it print?

Comment: @MadScientist: it print : amqp_connexion.o:
0000000000000000 T amqp_connexion

Comment: OK, obviously something you did is not the way we described it/we expect it.  Please _edit your question_ (it's hard to read formatted content in comments) and show the full link line and error messages you get.

Comment: @MadScientist: what is the full link line that we should add please ?

Comment: when you run make, it will print the link command it runs, before the errors are printed.  In your question you show it as `gcc amqp_consommateur.o -o amqp_consommateur`.  In the comments etc. we have explained to you that this is wrong and that you need to add the libraries, etc. to it.  You claim to have done that but you are still getting the errors.  So I'm asking you to show the current link line that is printed, so we can see what it currently says.

Comment: OK, please edit the question to be properly formatted.  Your newlines are all messed up which makes the output hard to read, and you shouldn't add extra characters like `>` etc. which are not present in the actual output.  However, if I'm interpreting it properly you didn't actually pay attention to my comment in the answer below.  I said, you have to be sure the library appears at the end of the line and above you said you did that and it didn't matter.  But in the output above, it's clear that the library does NOT come last; it still comes first.

Comment: Not only that but your link line doesn't actually contain your library at all: there's no `-lamqp` flag.  Instead you have `-lrabbitmq` which I don't know if it's needed or not, but you certainly have to have your library on the link line.

Comment: @MadScientist: Can you send me how can i organize my Makefile

Comment: @MadScientist: you have reason, i was added -lamqp in LDLIBS flag but it still the same problem

Comment: @MadScientist : i found the solution , thats is it , you should make the libs at the last--> $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the comment below.

Comment: @MadScientist, for that i attend to send me the correct line because in first I didn't understand your meaning. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -g
INCLUDES := -I/usr/local/include/ -I/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp/dlo 
LFLAGS := -L/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp
LDLIBS := -lrabbitmq -lamqp
SRCS := amqp_consommateur.c amqp_producteur.c
#LIBS := -L. -lamqp

OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
EXECS := $(SRCS:.c=)

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXECS)
    @echo "$(MAKE) : Tout est généré"

$(EXECS) : % : %.o Makefile 
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDLIBS) 

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECS) $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<
```

Answer (score -1):

Your program need to be linked against `rabbitMQ` library.

```
-lrabbimtq
```

I think you have to modify several lines in your makefile:

```
  LDFLAGS := -lrabbimtq
  LFLAGS  := -L/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp
```

and

```
    $(PROGS) : % : %.o Makefile 
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: It is wrong to put libraries first in the link line.  They must come last.  In your example, it means `$(LDFLAGS)` should come last.  But, the variable usage in your example are non-standard and thus will be confusing: normally `LDFLAGS` contains linker flags (the stuff you put in `LFLAGS`) and `LDLIBS` contains libraries (the stuff you put in `LDFLAGS`).

Comment: @Robert: i make this correction and the result is :  make
µgcc -lrabbitmq -L/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/libamqp amqp_consommateur.o -o amqp_consommateur
amqp_consommateur.o: In function `main':
/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp/amqp_consommateur.c:48: undefined reference to `amqp_connexion'
/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp/amqp_consommateur.c:49: undefined reference to `amqp_consommateur'
/home/tvi/projets/RabbitMQ/test_amqp/amqp_consommateur.c:50: undefined reference to `amqp_deconnexion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [amqp_consommateur] Error 1

Comment: @Embeded_developer because the `-l` must come **after** all of the `.o` files on the command line! Please read MadScientist's comment too.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : you can see the correct answer in the comment above, Thanks, i find it .

Comment: yes but it is not in the answer. The answer is wrong.